# axios Post returning error in react native

Tags: react-native, axios

i am using react native as front-end and backend i have laravel

i am tring to make a axios post request to api my api is working fine in postman

```
 function getdata() {
    const Data = {
    
      name: name,
      email: email,
      date: mydate,
    };

    console.log(Data);

    axios
      .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users', Data)

      .then(() => {
      
        alert('success submited');
    
     
      })

      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      });
  
  }
```

error :axiosError:Netwoek Error

Comment: Are you runnign this code on the same machine as your backend?

Comment: yes i am testing in local for react-native i have a emulator i start it with npx react-native run-android

Comment: Instead of using 127.0.0.1, use your actual ip address instead.

Comment: i used the ip adress but now theres no error but  .then funtion is not working @ caslawter